# Third party cookies disabled in Chrome on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, third-party-cookies

I want to detect if third party cookies are disabled or not. For this I wrote some code, but I was also using this site: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/are-third-party-cookies-enabled

In the Google **Chrome App on iOS** (iPhone) **third party cookies should be enabled by default** and it should not even be possible to disable them, according to the official documentation:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61416?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en

When I check on **my iPhone in Chrome** - I get the response that **third party cookies are disabled**. Cookies in general are enabled though.
The common behavior on other iPhones - same iOS and Chrome version - is that third party cookies are enabled - as expected.

Google Chrome version: 86.0.4240.93
iOS version: 13.7

I also even checked the browser settings for this google user account, in case it would affect it.

Does anybody have experience with that and knows if it's detecting it wrong, or if third party cookies are actually really disabled?

Answer (score 1):

3rd-party cookies are blocked by default on iOS 14 due to [ITP](https://webkit.org/tracking-prevention/). You can turn it off in Settings - Chrome - Check 'Allow cross-website tracking'.

Comment: Making this setting, did not help. I verified on iOS 15.